# ruby regex and multi-line strings

Tags: ruby, regex, string, pdf

I'm using the prawn gem to read through a 60 page computer-generated pdf report that contains financial and demographic data for dozens of individuals. The challenge I'm facing is that I want to be able to capture the name/special ID (on the same line) AND the subsequent lines that are related to that person while each line gets scanned. Using ruby's scan method for strings, I've been able to capture just the financial with each match returning lines in this way:

```
[<invoice no.>, <service type>, <modifier (if any)>, <service_date>, <units>, <amount>]
```

I've tried to associate the ID with the financial data several lines down, and then have it change whenever the ID changes but nothing has worked. Am I going about this in an ass-backwards way? My experience with regex is scant (and programming in general).

Below is the code that works with only the financial data:

```
PDF::Reader.new(file).pages.each do |page|
  page.raw_content.scan(/^\(\s(\d{6})\s+\d\s+(\w\d{4})\s+(0580|TT|1C|1C\s+1F)?\s+(\d+\/\d+\/\d+)\s+\d+\/\d+\/\d+\s+(\d+\.\d+)\s+(\d+\.\d+)/) do |line|        
    line.collect {|x| x.strip! if !x.nil?}
    print "#{line.join(' ')}\n"
    Cycle.check_details(line)
  end
end
```

And here's a sampling of what `puts page.raw_content` produces (there is a lot of empty whitespace contained in these lines).

```
(REG  LOC   CLIENT   SERVICE   NAME                    BIRTH DATE   RECIPIENT ID    PRIOR AUTHORIZATION #)'
(xx   xxx  xxxxx     xxxxxxx    LANNISTER, JAIME         xx/xx/xxxx   xxxx <special ID>)'
(DIAGNOSIS CODES:  887.0)'
( )'
(  INV #   LINE #   PROCEDURE CODE  REVENUE CD   FROM DT   THRU DT     UNITS AMOUNT)'
( <inv num>       1    <service_code>  <modifier>                    xx/xx/13  xx/xx/13     4.00     65.60)'
( <inv num>       2    <service_code>  <modifier>                    xx/xx/13  xx/xx/13     2.50     41.00)'
( <inv num>       3    <service_code>  <modifier>                    xx/xx/13  xx/xx/13     4.00     65.60)'
( <inv num>       4    <service_code>  <modifier>                    xx/xx/13  xx/xx/13     4.00     65.60)'
( <inv num>       5    <service_code>  <modifier>                    xx/xx/13  xx/xx/13     4.00     65.60)'
( <inv num>       6    <service_code>  <modifier>                    xx/xx/13  xx/xx/13     4.00     65.60)'
( <inv num>       7    <service_code>  <modifier>                    xx/xx/13  xx/xx/13     4.00     65.60)'
(                                                                CLAIM TOTAL
   434.60   CLAIM ACCOUNT REF.  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxSUP)'

(REG  LOC   CLIENT   SERVICE   NAME                    BIRTH DATE   RECIPIENT ID    PRIOR AUTHORIZATION #)'
(xx   xxx  xxxxx     xxxxxxx    LANNISTER, JOFFREY         xx/xx/xxxx   xxxx <special ID>)'
(DIAGNOSIS CODES:  259.0)'
( )'
(  INV #   LINE #   PROCEDURE CODE  REVENUE CD   FROM DT   THRU DT     UNITS AMOUNT)'
( <inv num>       1    <service_code>  <modifier>                    xx/xx/13  xx/xx/13     4.00     65.60)'
( <inv num>       2    <service_code>  <modifier>                    xx/xx/13  xx/xx/13     2.50     41.00)'
( <inv num>       3    <service_code>  <modifier>                    xx/xx/13  xx/xx/13     4.00     65.60)'
( <inv num>       4    <service_code>  <modifier>                    xx/xx/13  xx/xx/13     4.00     65.60)'
( <inv num>       5    <service_code>  <modifier>                    xx/xx/13  xx/xx/13     4.00     65.60)'
( <inv num>       6    <service_code>  <modifier>                    xx/xx/13  xx/xx/13     4.00     65.60)'
( <inv num>       7    <service_code>  <modifier>                    xx/xx/13  xx/xx/13     4.00     65.60)'
(                                                                CLAIM TOTAL
   434.60   CLAIM ACCOUNT REF.  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxSUP)'
```

Comment: Are you sure it is reading everything in correctly?

Comment: Your data is confusing, so I think you're not showing it correctly, or not parsing the PDF correctly. Lines should start and end with wrapping parenthesis, or with leading and trailing single-quotes. Instead, your lines start with left-parens and close with a single-quote. Please confirm what is correct, and if something is wrong with the data, please fix it.

Comment: @theTinMan, I've noticed this too and when I was initially learning how to use prawn, the sample code for displaying the text in terminal showed the same thing: `( )'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not everything is a candidate to be parsed with regex. And, sometimes regex is useful *after* you break the data into manageable chunks. Your data is an example of the second case. Once it's broken down some, individual lines can be easily parsed.

Your data is confusing, but this unravels it. Once the leading `(` and trailing `)'` are stripped, the code breaks it into individual lines using `split`, then uses `slice_before` to break it into logical chunks. Once those have been gathered, it's possible to process each block in a sensible manner:

```
require 'prettyprint'

data = "(REG  LOC   CLIENT   SERVICE   NAME                    BIRTH DATE   RECIPIENT ID    PRIOR AUTHORIZATION #)'
(xx   xxx  xxxxx     xxxxxxx    LANNISTER, JAIME         xx/xx/xxxx   xxxx <special ID>)'
(DIAGNOSIS CODES:  887.0)'
( )'
(  INV #   LINE #   PROCEDURE CODE  REVENUE CD   FROM DT   THRU DT     UNITS AMOUNT)'
( <inv num>       1    <service_code>  <modifier>                    xx/xx/13  xx/xx/13     4.00     65.60)'
( <inv num>       2    <service_code>  <modifier>                    xx/xx/13  xx/xx/13     2.50     41.00)'
( <inv num>       3    <service_code>  <modifier>                    xx/xx/13  xx/xx/13     4.00     65.60)'
( <inv num>       4    <service_code>  <modifier>                    xx/xx/13  xx/xx/13     4.00     65.60)'
( <inv num>       5    <service_code>  <modifier>                    xx/xx/13  xx/xx/13     4.00     65.60)'
( <inv num>       6    <service_code>  <modifier>                    xx/xx/13  xx/xx/13     4.00     65.60)'
( <inv num>       7    <service_code>  <modifier>                    xx/xx/13  xx/xx/13     4.00     65.60)'
(                                                                CLAIM TOTAL
  434.60   CLAIM ACCOUNT REF.  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxSUP)'

(REG  LOC   CLIENT   SERVICE   NAME                    BIRTH DATE   RECIPIENT ID    PRIOR AUTHORIZATION #)'
(xx   xxx  xxxxx     xxxxxxx    LANNISTER, JOFFREY         xx/xx/xxxx   xxxx <special ID>)'
(DIAGNOSIS CODES:  259.0)'
( )'
(  INV #   LINE #   PROCEDURE CODE  REVENUE CD   FROM DT   THRU DT     UNITS AMOUNT)'
( <inv num>       1    <service_code>  <modifier>                    xx/xx/13  xx/xx/13     4.00     65.60)'
( <inv num>       2    <service_code>  <modifier>                    xx/xx/13  xx/xx/13     2.50     41.00)'
( <inv num>       3    <service_code>  <modifier>                    xx/xx/13  xx/xx/13     4.00     65.60)'
( <inv num>       4    <service_code>  <modifier>                    xx/xx/13  xx/xx/13     4.00     65.60)'
( <inv num>       5    <service_code>  <modifier>                    xx/xx/13  xx/xx/13     4.00     65.60)'
( <inv num>       6    <service_code>  <modifier>                    xx/xx/13  xx/xx/13     4.00     65.60)'
( <inv num>       7    <service_code>  <modifier>                    xx/xx/13  xx/xx/13     4.00     65.60)'
(                                                                CLAIM TOTAL
  434.60   CLAIM ACCOUNT REF.  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxSUP)'
"

lines = data.gsub(/^\(|\)'$/m, '').split("\n").map{ |s| s.strip }.reject{ |s| s.empty? }.slice_before(/^REG\b/)
```

At this point, `lines` is an array of arrays. Each sub-array consists of blocks of lines starting with "REG". Each time `slice_before` sees a new line matching `/^REG\b/` it creates a new sub-array/block. `lines` is an enumerator, which is like the preliminary object prior to getting an array or single key/value pair from a hash. You can iterate over enumerators, which is what we want to do:

```
patient_data = lines.map { |sub_ary|
  sub_ary[1][/(?:\S+ \s+ ){4} (\S+, \s+ \S+) \s+ (?:\S+ \s+){2} (.+)$/x]
  patient_name, special_id = $1, $2

  invoice_info = sub_ary[5..-3].map{ |line|
    line[/^(\S+) \s+ \S+ \s+ (\S+) \s+ (\S+)/x]
    [$1, $2, $3]
  }

  {
    patient_name: patient_name,
    special_id:   special_id,
    invoice_info: invoice_info
  }
}

pp patient_data
```

Which outputs:

```
[{:patient_name=>"LANNISTER, JAIME",
  :special_id=>"<special ID>",
  :invoice_info=>
  [["<inv_num>", "<service_code>", "<modifier>"],
    ["<inv_num>", "<service_code>", "<modifier>"],
    ["<inv_num>", "<service_code>", "<modifier>"],
    ["<inv_num>", "<service_code>", "<modifier>"],
    ["<inv_num>", "<service_code>", "<modifier>"],
    ["<inv_num>", "<service_code>", "<modifier>"]]},
{:patient_name=>"LANNISTER, JOFFREY",
  :special_id=>"<special ID>",
  :invoice_info=>
  [["<inv_num>", "<service_code>", "<modifier>"],
    ["<inv_num>", "<service_code>", "<modifier>"],
    ["<inv_num>", "<service_code>", "<modifier>"],
    ["<inv_num>", "<service_code>", "<modifier>"],
    ["<inv_num>", "<service_code>", "<modifier>"],
    ["<inv_num>", "<service_code>", "<modifier>"]]}]
```

This gets you close but doesn't solve the question completely. I'm deliberately leaving it up to you figure out how to modify the code to grab all the fields you want from the records.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I've noticed that you use `$1`, etc. for regex. I assume that each number simply corresponds with whatever regex matches in sequence? I tried adding more incrementally into the `invoice_info` part, and I got the rest of the invoice info that I needed but want to make sure that's what it actually does.

Comment: Don't assume. Read [the documentation for Regexp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Regexp.html). There are several ways to retrieve the capture groups and sometimes one way makes more sense than another.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test out your regex check out http://rubular.com/

It is a very useful tool and has most of the basics for a regex at the bottom of the page